# C# alias for class public static member?

Tags: c#

I have class RenderManager which has public static member TheRenderer. Instead of RenderManager.TheRenderer can I create alias for that like MyRenderer or whatever?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by alias for a member.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423809/how-to-import-a-static-class-in-c

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class or method-level symbol which points to that object, but you can't create a truly global alias which points to that object, no. It would still have to be namespaced in some other object.

Locally, though (inside a function or class) you could do something like `var renderer = RenderManager.TheRenderer`, but you would have to do that everywhere you want to use that alias.

Comment: Right, that way you have to do it everywhere.I was hoping there is other way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. The only possibility is to make an alias for `Type` and not for its members, something like this:

```
using rnd = RendererManager; 

//and in code somewhere use 

rnd.TheRenderer
```

Hope I right understood what you mean.

Comment: What I came to this question looking to ask was whether it would be possible to do something like `using r = RendererManager.TheRenderer;`. Is it possible? The compiler doesn’t seem to let me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean `var MyRenderer = RenderManager.TheRenderer;`? i.e. assigning the value of the static member to a variable called `MyRenderer`?

---

Not that unlike valipour's solution, if the `RenderManager.TheRenderer` value changes after you assign it, `MyRenderer` will have the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable of type Func or Action.

If TheRenderer has return value:

```
static Func<bool> MyRenderer = () => RenderManager.TheRenderer();
```

If not:

```
static Action MyRenderer = () => RenderManager.TheRenderer();
```

if TheRenderer accepts some input parameters then you should use other forms of Func<> and Action<>.

```
Func<OutT, In1T, In2T, ...>
Action<In1T, In2T, ...>
```

Comment: This works, except that you need to call the `Invoke()` method, i.e. `MyRenderer.Invoke()`, before you can access `RenderManager.TheRenderer()`'s returned value.