# Functions in a namespace?

Tags: c#, function, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why C# is not allowing non-member functions like C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024171/why-c-sharp-is-not-allowing-non-member-functions-like-c)

Instead of writing `StaticClass.Function()` I'd like to simply write `Function()`. There will be many functions and all should be accessible from different (and unrelated) classes and files. How do I put these functions in a specific namespace? Simply declaring it there will give me a compile error

```
error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

I know other .NET languages can do it. Is there a compile option i may use? Perhaps even undocumented?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to define a "global" method, though you could write Function() inside the class itself. There's really no need, though..

Comment: BTW, you don't want to do this. They _can_ be accessed from various classes, you just have to say which class.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I do really want to do this. All the functions are neatly placed in a namespace and i'd like to access them if i include the namespace. I can't possibly think of why C# would allow gotos and not this. Really...

Comment: ugh, not worth the time to implement is what the article said. I guess that answers it. thanks @EdS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# does not allow for free functons.  Each function must reside in a type.  This is just the way it works, it's not a matter of technical possibility, it was a design decision.

You may be interested in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx).

---

On a side note, ever notice how Intellisense works much, *much* better when writing C# than C++?  This is one of those things that help (not the only one, but one).

EDIT: Funny, in reading that linked article I noticed that this is a dup...

Comment: FYI, VS2012 has a bunch of C++ editor/IntelliSense improvements. :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Yes, it does.  Actually, even 2010 was a *huge* step forward in terms of C++ intellisense (and a huge step *backward* in terms of performance, but that is neither hear nor there...).  C++ Intellisense in 2005 was a joke, never used 2008.  So yeah, it's getting better, but it is so much easier to implement for a language like C#.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not allow this, [by design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx).

However, if your goal is merely to reduce typing, you have a couple of options.

First, you can use the [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to simplify this.  By adding this:

```
using SC = YourNamespace.StaticClass;
```

You can shorten the calls within that specific document to:

```
SC.Function();
```

Another option which is occasionally appropriate would be to use an
[Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This can eliminate the need to specify the type, as the function appears to be a member function of the first argument.  Of course, this wouldn't work for the supplied example (as it requires a parameter), but is potentially another option to reduce the amount of typing and searching, depending on the specific use case.

Answer (score -2):

C# is a purely object-oriented which means you cannot have functions or declarations outside of a class. You'll have to use static to achieve what you want.

Comment: -1 OO doesn't mandate that all functions belong to a class.  Actually, it doesn't mandate that "classes" even exist.  Classes are simply one way of implementing OOP (data structures of *some* sort are of course required).  Also, Eric Lipper doesn't mention this *at all* when explaining the decision. (he does mention however that "C# is a *component*-oriented language")